# Python: Write function in module to import packages

Tags: python, function, import, python-module

I am trying to write a function, which is itself loaded, to quickly import a bunch of modules globally.

I thought that, essentially, loaded modules could be treated as variables so I tried:

```
def loadMods():
    global np
    import numpy as np
```

and when I loaded numpy (calling np) there was no problem.

What I then did was to create a separate .py file called loadTest containing

```
# loadTest module
# coding: utf-8

def loadMod():
     global np
     import numpy as np
```

Then attempted to import numpy using this .py file in python (2.7):

```
import loadTest
loadTest.loadMod()
```

but now when attempting calling np I get

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

Why does this occur? Any help or alternative ways of doing this would be much appreciated. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: All you've done is to make `np` available inside your `loadTest` module, which doesn't really help at all.

Comment: Thats kind of what I was expecting. Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of making a function to do this, why not make another module?  You could name it something like `modules.py` and put all of your imports in there:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
...
```

Then, all you need to do is a [wildcard import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-import_stmt):

```
from modules import *
```

and everything will be made available.

Answer (score -1):

You must first define `np` like that.

In `loadTest`:

```
np=None
```

In somewhere other

```
import loadTest
loadTest.loadMod()
np=loadTest.np
```

Comment: This won't work. Each module's global namespace is separate, and so the `global` statement in `loadMod` will only ever write the `np` name in its own module.